# How to get Initial Value of Field by Mono Cecil?

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

I'm trying to use Mono Cecil to get Initial Value as String of public field in DLL.
Here is my code in Class Library:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static string testField = "abc";
    }
}
```

How can I get "abc" ?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://mono-cecil.narkive.com/SR0BvKaP/how-to-get-initial-value-of-fields-when-value-is-a-string

Comment: @brijber that link have no answer, but thank for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure Cecil provides an API to retrieve this information but since instance fields are initialized at the type's **constructor** and **static fields** in the **static constructor** you can look for stores to the desired field. For instance, given this class:

```
  .method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
        void .cctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x205f
        // Code size 21 (0x15)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldstr "Foo"
        IL_0005: stsfld string Program::'value'
        IL_000a: call string Program::MyFunction()
        IL_000f: stsfld string Program::value2
        IL_0014: ret
    } // end of method Program::.cctor
```

you can do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;

namespace CecilRetrieveInitializer
{
    class Program
    {
        static Program()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In cctor..");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location))
            {
                var t = a.MainModule.GetType("CecilRetrieveInitializer.Program");
                var f = t.Fields.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == "value");
                Console.WriteLine(InitialValue(t, f));
                Console.WriteLine(InitialValue(t, t.Fields.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == "value2")));
            }

            string InitialValue(TypeDefinition t, FieldDefinition f)
            {
                var cctor = t.Methods.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == ".cctor");
                if (cctor == null)
                    throw new Exception("no field initialization...");

                var store = cctor.Body.Instructions.SingleOrDefault(i => i.OpCode == OpCodes.Stsfld && i.Operand == f);
                if (store.Previous.Operand.GetType() != typeof(string))
                    return store.Previous.Operand.ToString();

                return (string) store.Previous.Operand;
            }
        }

        static string MyFunction() => "Bar";

        public static string value = "Foo";
        public static string value2 = MyFunction();
        public const string value3 = "Bar";
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the field may be initialized with a **non const** value in which case you'll probably not be able (to easily) retrieve the value (see **value2**).

Also, note that if you declare your field as **const** you can use **Constant** property:

```
f = t.Fields.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == "value3");
Console.WriteLine(f.Constant);
```